# Why do foreach loop variables show 1 set when there should be more

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach

I imported a CSV file and reduced the imported information to contain 2 rows of data (`$updateAnchorage`), and when I call `$updateAnchorage`, it contains the data I would expect. Then I created 2 hash tables from the imported data using a foreach loop, as I will show you below. I am trying to understand PowerShell better, so my question is why does `$row` in the foreach loop only give a single row of data when I would expect it to show 2 rows?

Here is the code and results:

```
$updateA = Import-Csv -Path C:\Windows\System32\MyFile-CSV.csv `
        -Header "name","old","new" | select -Skip 2
$hashIP = @{}
$hashName = @{}

foreach($row in $updateA)
{
    $hashIP[$row.old] = $row.new
    $hashName[$row.new] = $row.Name   
}
```

Here is the output of `$updateA` and `$rows`:

> PS C:\Users\a> $updateA
>   name                                     old                                      new
>   ----                                     ---                                      ---
>   City - HP LaserJet 4250N - Sales... 192.168.2.120                          192.168.2.50
>   City - Lexmark XM1145 - Sales Co... 192.168.2.106                          192.168.2.51
>
> PS C:\Users\a> $row
>
> name                                     old                                      new
>   ----                                     ---                                      ---
>   City - Lexmark XM1145 - Sales Co... 192.168.2.106                          192.168.2.51

Comment: I posted an answer to the specific question of why `$row` only has one value but can you clarify your end goal with the script? It doesn't really make sense to split the CSV in to two hash tables when the imported CSV is already an object of the type `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` which can be worked with and is more powerful than hash tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Row will be the last thing to go through the foreach construct. You need to call either $hashIP or $hashName.

This is what your script creates:

```
[nickj@nick-lt scripts]$ $hashIP

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2.2.2.2                        2.2.2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1.1.1.1                        1.1.1.2                                                                                                                                                                                                               

[nickj@nick-lt scripts]$ $hashName

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2.2.2.3                        Name2                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1.1.1.2                        Name1
```

My CSV:

```
"Name","Old","New"
Name1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2
Name2,2.2.2.2,2.2.2.3
```

If you did something simple like this:

```
$Array = 1,2,3,4,5

foreach ($Num in $Array)
{
    continue
}
```

When it is done running `$Num` which is equivelent to your `$Row` would be '5' as it would be the last thing from the array to pass through the foreach construct. It is essentially doing this:

```
$Array = 1,2,3,4,5

$Num = $Array[0]
# Continue

$Num = $Array[1]
# Continue

$Num = $Array[2]
# Continue

$Num = $Array[3]
# Continue

$Num = $Array[4]
# Continue
```

So through each loop $Num is set to the current array value it's working on. If you picture it as `foreach (<WHAT> in <COLLECTION>) {}` you should only ever reference `<WHAT>` inside the foreach's braces. It becomes useless to you outside.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration, that really clears it up for me. That makes perfect sense and will definitely help me in future use of the foreach loops. To answer your question, I have a column of "old" IPs that are no longer valid for our use and we want to remove them from the printer IPs and replace them with the "new" IPs. Then based off the "new" IPs, I need to recreate the existing printers and use our new naming convention. So 1 hash has the old/new key/value pair, the other has the new/name key/value pair. This was the best way I could figure to keep track of it all.

Comment: You're better off with a CSV that's something like: `"OldName","NewName","OldIP","NewIP"` then when you do `$CSV = Import-CSV whatever.csv` you can do `foreach ($Printer in $CSV)` and work with `$Printer.OldName` or `$Printer.NewIP` or whatever... If you look up pscustomobject's that is what PowerShell is creating when you `Import-CSV`.

Comment: I had been looking for some sources that would tell me exactly that a while back and couldn't find what I was looking for. I must not have been phrasing it right. I will definitely keep that in mind, because that would've saved me a lot of heartache. You're awesome, thank you.